# Synchronize between local database server (dynamic ip) and online database server (static ip)

Tags: java, mysql, database, web, synchronization

Currently i have one project need to synchronize between local database and online database. The local database need to real time update to the online database for specific table. Then the online database also need to real time update to local database for specific table. But the local database server's ip address is dynamic.

For example,
When Local database's table A and B have changes, it need to update to online server. Then, when online database's table C have changes, it need to update to the local server, but the local server has no static ip.

So how can i do to accomplish? I have research MySQL Replication before, but it is one way sync only, so i think i cannot use it in this project. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need master to master way?

Comment: @Arios can master to master? I thought only can master to slave.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java]? It can all be done with MySQL configuration.

Comment: @EJP may I know how to accomplish? Because the local server don't have static ip or domain name.

Comment: And I am using java to code my back end.